How to include function return values in SQLModel/FastAPI Response class?
In my DocumentPublic class, i want to include a field "doc_type_name". This is not saved in my database but fetched via external request.
My current solution looks like this:
class DocumentPublic(DocumentBase):
    id: int
    doc_type: int
    doc_type_name: str | None = None
    # ...

    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        self.doc_type_name = get_doc_type_name(self.doc_type)

In my fastapi functions, I then return documents like this:
return [DocumentPublic(**document.dict() for document in documents]

It works, but isn't clean and I assume there must be a better way. But i couldn't find anything.
Thank you for your help.

Did you see https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.0/usage/computed_fields/ ? Generally I'd recommend against making external requests on field access as they can be rather magical (and especially if doc_type is shared among multiple documents as it'd end up with a request per document). Having a "doc type populator" class that fetches the mapping on startup and keeps it available in memory (and refetches if necessary) might be an alternative.

Thanks, thats exactly what i needed. "get_doc_type_name()" is cached for some hours, so i think too many requests shouldn't be an issue.
